# Java 8: Как отфильтровать список в одном лямбда-выражении по разным условиям?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8, lambda, predicate

Начал изучать лямбда-выражения и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Вот, например, у меня есть такой метод:

```
public List<String> someFilter() {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B");

    Predicate<String> itemsAPredicate = itemA -> StringUtils.equals("A", itemA);

    List<String> itemsASet = items.stream()
            .filter(itemsAPredicate)
            .map(itemsA -> method1(itemsA))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    items.stream()
            .filter(itemsAPredicate.negate())
            .map(otherItem -> method2(otherItem))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).addAll(itemsASet);

    return items;
}
```

Что я пытаюсь сделать. Список `items` содержит строки, которые могут быть отфильтрованы по какому-то условию, например - все строки `А`. Эти строки потом обрабатываются в каком-то методе `method1` и результат помещается в список. А вот которые не прошли условие? B, C, D... Можно ли как-то совместить в одном лямбда-выражении обработку и этих строк? Что-то типа else в фильтре, или как-то по-другому можно?

Comment: Отказатся от фильтра и сделать функцию(Function<A,B>), в которой провернуть эту логику. Проверять в ней что пришло и вызывать тот или иной метод

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему в вашем коде возвращается первоначальный список `items`.  Похоже, что подразумевалось сначала отфильтровать строки, удовлетворяющие предикату, а затем преобразовать их и добавить в конец нового списка.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, ошибся - вы правы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае вместо `Stream::filter` следует применить коллектор `Collectors.partitioningBy`, который построит хэш-таблицу с булевым ключом, используя заданный предикат.  Также можно будет применить `Collectors.mapping` для вызова `method1` или `method2`.  Тогда за один проход можно будет разбить исходный список на два, содержащий преобразованные данные:

```java
public List<String> someFilter() {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B");

    Predicate<String> itemsAPredicate = itemA -> StringUtils.equals("A", itemA);

    Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
            itemsAPredicate,
            Collectors.mapping(item -> itemsAPredicate.test(item) 
                ? method1(item) : method2(item),
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        ));

    return map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) // NOT predicate first
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Более сокращённая форма без создания промежуточной переменной `map`:

```java
public List<String> someFilter() {
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B");

    Predicate<String> itemsAPredicate = itemA -> StringUtils.equals("A", itemA);

    return items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
            itemsAPredicate,
            Collectors.mapping(item -> itemsAPredicate.test(item) 
                ? method1(item) : method2(item),
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )) // Map<Boolean, List<String>>
        .entrySet()
        .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Boolean, List<String>>>
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) // NOT predicate first
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()) // Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Для теста допустим, что методы `method1`, `method2` реализованы так:

```java
private static String method1(String s) {return s + " is aa";}
private static String method2(String s) {return s + " not A";}

System.out.println(someFilter());
// -> [B not A, C not A, D not A, B not A, A is aa, A is aa]
```

Comment: Превосходно, благодарю.